# Joda-Time cannot find class "forPattern()"

Tags: java, android, jodatime, datetime-format

im trying format a date using Joda-Time v 2.8.2, all the similar answers i have found say to use a method forPattern(), but with the version I am using it tells me that there is no such method(), am I using it incorrectly? or is this method deprecated or something? if so, what method is it replaced with if any?

Relevant code:

```
static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";


public String timeSince(String dateString) {

    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                              new DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    Seconds secondsSince = Seconds.secondsBetween(DateTime.parse(dateString, formatter),
                                                      DateTime.now());

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cannot find class “forPattern()”` is one thing, and `tells me that there is no such method()` is a totally different thing.

What is actually happening is that `new Class.Function()` is a syntax error.

So, java got confused, it thinks you must be trying to invoke a constructor, so it is telling you that it cannot find the class that contains such a constructor.

Solution: drop the `new`.

Comment: hahah, silly mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[`forPattern`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)) is a static method. Remove the new keyword

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
```